# OS X: Storing MySQL data securely, on an encrypted FileVault image using a soft link

Tags: macos, permissions, mysql, filevault

I am trying to get a macports-installed MySQL to use a data directory stored inside my FileVault-protected home dir.

I used `sudo cp -a /opt/local/var/db/mysql5 ~/db/` (the `-a` to ensure file permissions remain intact) and then replaced the original mysql5 directory with a soft link: `sudo ln -s ~/db/mysql5 /opt/local/var/db/mysql5`

However, when I now try to start MySQL it fails. It follows the soft link at least to the extent that it modifies some files in the `~/db/mysql5` dir, notably the error log which gets appended to it this:

```
110108 15:33:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /opt/local/var/db/mysql5
110108 15:33:08 [Warning] '--skip-locking' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--skip-external-locking' instead.
110108 15:33:08 [Warning] '--log_slow_queries' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use ''--slow_query_log'/'--slow_query_log_file'' instead.
110108 15:33:08 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.
110108 15:33:08 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/local/var/db/mysql5/ is case insensitive
110108 15:33:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
110108 15:33:08 [Note] Plugin 'ndbcluster' is disabled.
/opt/local/libexec/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
110108 15:33:08 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
110108 15:33:09  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 4 1596664332
110108 15:33:09 [ERROR] /opt/local/libexec/mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/mac.local.pid' (Errcode: 13)
110108 15:33:09 [ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: Permission denied
110108 15:33:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /opt/local/var/db/mysql5/gPod.local.pid ended
```

I can't see why MySQL can't create the `pid` file, since manually creating it using the `_mysql` user succeeds (`sudo -u _mysql touch mac.local.pid` from inside `~/db/mysql5`)

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: I am not a mysql user, but it seems to me that the "cp -a" should have been "cp -R", in case `/opt/local/var/db/mysql5` had sub-directories.

Comment: For a moment I thought @harrymc figured that `-a` does not include `-R`, while it does: `-a Same as -pPR`. But I guess it's the implicit `-P` that Harry is referring to? `-P If the -R option is specified, no symbolic links are followed.` Might indeed be an issue.

Comment: Ooops, I guess "not followed" does not mean it does not *create* new symbolic links while copying. I guess it just implies it's not going to duplicate its content...? If true, then `cp -a` is fine after all.

Comment: @Arjan: No, I only got a very old page when searching for "cp man page". But I still think the poster should verify his cp result, just in case.

Comment: @GJ: Have you verified that the cp target was identical to the source on ALL attributes before replacing it by the link? And why did you use cp rather than mv? Do you have a backup of the replaced old directory?

Comment: How is mysqld_safe being invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tait Lewis explained very well the issue with the execute permission.
However doing that to a real user account is both a security risk and may potentially prevent legitimate execution by other `staff` group members.

The way I solved the same problem was as follows:

- Create a new standard user account (for this example we'll call it `db`) with FileVault enabled for it. Use a password at least as strong as that of your primary user.
- While logged in as your primary user, run the following commands:
- mount the FileVault image of the db user, without making it browsable in the Finder:

`sudo hdiutil attach /Users/db/db.sparsebundle -owners on -mountpoint /Users/db -nobrowse`

- Fix the permissions so that the `_mysql` user can execute the db user's home directory:

`sudo chown :_mysql /Users/db; sudo chmod g=x /Users/db`

- Shutdown MySQL:

`sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper stop`

- Copy the MySQL files into the FileVault:

`sudo cp -a /opt/local/var/db/mysql5 /Users/db/` (do NOT add a `/` after `mysql5`)

- Now you either delete, secure delete, or just rename the `/opt/local/var/db/mysql5` directory.
- Next, create the soft link:

`sudo ln -s /Users/db/mysql5 /opt/local/var/db/mysql5`

- Finally, start MySQL again:

`sudo /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5/mysql5.wrapper start`

Note that every time you reboot the Mac you'll need to mount the image (with the `sudo hdiutil ...` command) and start MySQL manually as it will fail to mount when launchd tries to start it automatically before the image is mounted.

Answer (score 1):

I've commented on one of your similar questions, since I think there's a better way to [store MySQL data in an encrypted state](https://superuser.com/questions/228777/how-to-store-the-data-of-mysql-on-os-x-in-an-encrypted-state).

---

This sounds like a permissions issue. On your home folder, FileVault sets permissions to `rwx------` (i.e. owner can read, write and execute, but the group and other users have no permissions), versus the default `rwxr-xr-x` of a typical folder.

The factor in play here is that [execute permissions allow a user to search (a.k.a. traverse) the folder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Permissions). So when the `_mysql` user invokes `mysqld` and it follows the symlink, it chokes trying to traverse your home folder. It's `mysqld_safe` that writes the error messages to the log, using the permissions of the user that invoked it (probably root if `mysqld_safe` is started using the MacPorts startup script, `sudo /path/to/mysqld_safe` or similar.)

You can test this hypothesis by running the following commands in sequence:

```
$ cd ~/db/mysql5/
$ sudo -u _mysql touch mac.local.pid
```

should succeed because there's no traversal involved, and

```
$ sudo -u _mysql touch ~/db/mysql5/mac.local.pid
$ sudo -u _mysql touch /Users/[username]/db/mysql5/mac.local.pid
```

should both fail, but

```
$ sudo -u _mysql touch ../mac.local.pid
```

will probably succeed, since `~/db/` probably has the more lenient default folder permissions mentioned earlier.

A straightforward solution would be to set the group on your home folder to `_mysql`, and give the group permissions to search your home folder:

```
$ sudo chown :_mysql ~
$ chmod g=x ~
```

but this has **serious security ramifications**. Anyone acting as the `_mysql` user (potentially through a vulnerability in MySQL) could navigate into your home folder and manipulate files and folders according to their permissions, by default `rwxr-xr-x` for folders and `rw-r--r--` for files. As we saw earlier, this includes `~/db/` and any user-created folders or files, as well as `~/Public/` and `~/Sites/`. Even though an attacker couldn't directly get a listing of files in your home folder, there are plenty of common files to read, and many ways to use them to gather data about what else is laying around. (`.bash_history` springs to mind.)

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you haven't already done so, be sure to verify that your version of MySQL will support symlinks for the table(s) in question.  According to [this 2008 article](http://crazytoon.com/2008/05/02/mysql-how-do-you-use-symlinks-with-mysql-tables/), symlinks were only supported for MyISAM tables at that time and "For files used by tables for other storage engines, you may get strange problems if you try to use symbolic links."

Once you're convinced that your version of MySQL should support what you're doing, double-check which user you're trying to start `mysqld_safe` as and compare that against the permissions on `/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/`.  Since you used `cp -a`, it's likely that the directory is owned and writable by the _mysql user (which is why it works when you `sudo -u _mysql touch...`), but you're getting failures when trying to start MySQL from your normal user account (which isn't _mysql and, therefore, wouldn't have write access to the directory).

Comment: The article shows a trick how to avoid manually creating the symlink. As far as I understand, if the permissions are right and there are no special caveats imposed by the FileVault system, the symlinking should be totally transparent to MySQL and hence it's not an issue of MySQL compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This may be far fetched, but if you are soft linking to a separate partition, you could always mount that partition at the soft link point, then do a soft link where you would normally mount it.